# django selenium liveserver ignores css

Tags: django, selenium

When I create a test and I request a view I have two options.

1. Running the django dev server and call `self.selenium.get('http://localhost:8000' + reverse('my_view'))`
2. Using the selenium live server and call `self.selenium.get(self.live_server_url + reverse('my_view'))`

The problem with the first option is that it's a hardcoded location.
The problem with the second option is that the live server does not request css and js files. so its just pure HTML

**How it should look:**
[image]

**How it actually looks:**
[image]

Am I missing anything why the css and js files are not requested?

Base Testfile setup:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver


class SeleniumTests(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(SeleniumTests, cls).setUpClass()
        cls.selenium = WebDriver()

        lang_cookie = cls.selenium.get_cookie('django_language')
        browser_lang = cls.selenium.execute_script("return window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language")

        translation.activate(lang_cookie if lang_cookie != None else browser_lang)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()
        super(SeleniumTests, cls).tearDownClass()

    def test_login_form(self):
        url = self.live_server_url + reverse('...')
        self.selenium.get(url)
```

I use `geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64.`

Comment: Don't say no one has an idea???

Comment: wow no one.....

Comment: I figured out that it has to do with the line `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'`. If I remove it the CSS files are loaded but then the versioning is not working.